# Convert GeoTIFF coordinate system without losing quality?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

When converting a GeoTIFF from EPSG:3794 to EPSG:4326 using QGIS I am noticing a major loss in overall quality, especially with straight lines such as roads, parking marks, etc. The original is 4500 columns x 6000 rows and when converting I am given the automatic option to convert it to 4686 columns x 5974 rows (I'm not an expert, but I'm guessing this has something to do with the offset). If I override this and set the output as 9000x12000, the quality remains unchained, but the size jumps ups from 100 to 400 MB.

Before: 
[image]

After:
[image]

Secondly, is there an easy way to save the GeoTIFF with a JPG compression in QGIS? I'm able to to it in Global Mapper, but I would like to use one program for my conversions (I'm jet to figure out how to re-project GeoTiff/Shapefiles in Global Mapper).

Comment: Use Raster-Projections-Warp and select some other resampling method than Nearest neighbor that is the default. For JPEG compression select the respective alternative from Advanced parameters.

Comment: FYI, anytime you change coordinate systems you will "lose quality" because you must resample to a new grid. You can use higher resolutions (as you tried) and, as user30184 suggested, different resampling schemes to achieve a desired quality. As you found, altering the resolution doesn't matter much if you use nearest neighbor. Also, it's advisable to create a new post for each question you ask :)

Comment: @user30184 that worked perfectly. BUT, why does the Windows thumbnail of the  exports made by following the Raster>Projections-Warp path looks different, than those made by selecting Layer - Save as, while using the same settings? [link](https://i.imgur.com/MJ8eRGZ.jpg) It almost looks like Windows is generating preview in the wrong coordinate system, which is weird, because both files load perfectly when imported.

Comment: Perhaps one or the other method creates an image with pixels which are non-square in geographical units. GIS clients know how to stretch the pixels for viewing but generic image viewers do not. Check the pixel size from the image info to see if my guess is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't currently answer your first question as written, so I'm only answering to your request for help with JPEG compression settings.

GeoTIFF with JPEG compression:
Settings -> Options -> GDAL -> GTiff -> Edit Create Options
Add parameters and values to match the below image.
[image]
gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=75 -co JPEGTABLESMODE=1 -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co INTERLEAVE=PIXEL -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES
```

Once this profile is setup, you should not need to mess with it again, and will simply be able to choose it from the Profile drop-down on the creation settings dialog when exporting/saving raster data from QGIS.

Comment: Got it to work, but I had to remove PHOTOMETRIC, or I get "PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR not supported on a 4-band raster: only compatible of a 3-band (RGB) raster", could you elaborate? Also Could you point me to a terminal guide for QGIS? How do I use the code you provided in the terminal? I've also tried with this: "gdal_translate \ -co COMPRESS=JPEG \ -co TILED=YES \ B024262.tif B024262.tif _JPEG.tif", but all I get are SyntaxErrors.

Comment: If there is a transparency band, no, you can't use JPEG compression. You'll need to drop the transparency band and instead use NoData values. Look at the GDAL documentation, there isn't a terminal for QGIS per se quite yet. Yes, that syntax is wrong. Where did you attempt to enter that?

Comment: Plugins > Pyhton Console. Could you showcase an example on how to enter your code through the Pyhton Console to change the GDAL? I'm new to QGIS, so I'm a bit lost. I might be understanding guides wrong and you are supposed to enter it manually. Example: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html

Comment: I don't know how to use PyQGIS and the Python console. The commands (and the guide you linked) are for usage on the command-line against the gdal_translate executable itself directly. It would be located in your QGIS install directory under the /bin/ folder.